# What are the requirements for the content parameter in Frame.Navigate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm writing a WPF library where I make use of the [`Frame.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602273(v=vs.110).aspx) method. I'm curious to know, what are the requirements for the `content` parameter passed into the method? Does it require the object to be a subclass of the [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx) class? If so, then why doesn't it take a Page instead of an object parameter?

I tried looking into the WPF source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Frame.cs,75f38779139cc184), but I eventually gave up after 10 methods down. MSDN is also pretty vague; it just says ["the object that contains the content to navigate to."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602273(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can someone tell me the requirements for this method? Obviously something like `Frame.Navigate("Hello world")` wouldn't work, so what criteria does the parameter need to meet?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `Frame.Navigate("Hello world")` works without problems.

There is no limitation on what you can set as the `content` parameter.

Quote from WPF Unleashed about `Frame`:

> The `Frame` control holds arbitrary content, just like all other content
>   controls, but it isolates the content from the rest of the user
>   interface. For example, properties that would normally be inherited
>   down the element tree stop when they reach the `Frame`. In many
>   respects, WPF `Frame`s act like frames in HTML.

So it's just another content control, which separates its content from the rest of the application (by not inheriting properties) and offering built-in navigation.